# Realm serializing entity by using Kotlin and GSON endless loop

Tags: android, serialization, kotlin, realm, gson

Entity defined

```
open class Person : RealmObject() {
    var age: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}


class PersonSerializer : JsonSerializer<Person> {
    override fun serialize(src: Person, typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement {
        val jsonObject = JsonObject()
        jsonObject.addProperty("name", src.name)
        jsonObject.addProperty("age", src.age)
        return jsonObject
    }
}
```

Serialize by GSON

```
        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        val person = realm.where(Person::class.java).findFirst()
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setExclusionStrategies(object : ExclusionStrategy {
                    override fun shouldSkipField(f: FieldAttributes): Boolean {
                        return f.declaringClass == RealmObject::class.java
                    }

                    override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>): Boolean {
                        return false
                    }
                })
                .registerTypeAdapter(Person::class.java, PersonSerializer())
                .create()

        val personJSON = gson.toJson(person)
        Log.d("MainActivity", "$personJSON")
        realm.close()
```

It cause a endless loop. But if I change to

```
  val personJSON = gson.toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(person))
```

The entity serialized fine.
I just translate the realm gson demo from java to kotlin with the official document 
https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/ddac8efd018123a1e53a

I don't know what happened in my Kotlin

Comment: How do you know if it's an endless loop and not just taking time? Do you get a stack overflow exception or something similar?

Comment: It's a very long time and log read EOF in GSON, if I didn't kill the app. And if I use val personJSON = gson.toJson(realm.copyFromRealm(person)), it's done very quickly.